# Which is correct on echo variable

Tags: php, html-title

I'm Appserve with `PHP 5.2` and this code was working fine

```
<?PHP
// after connection to DB and getting title from setting table
$title = $line['wptitle'];
?>
<title><?=$title?></title>
```

But after I've start using Vertrigo Serv with `PHP 5.3`, the above code no longer shows the title and only if I edit it to

```
<title><?PHP echo $title; ?></title>
```

Is `<?=$title?>` is no longer acceptable?

Comment: [answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgkl8.png) <- I think this makes it easy to decide

Comment: The use of `<?=` is a PHP configuration option. There's an entry in `php.ini` that enables it.

Comment: @Rizier123 dat wz very straight and clear .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that in your php.ini file you have:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

as well you can put in your .htaccess file:

```
php_flag short_open_tag on
```